# How to store TaskID for later use?

Tags: designer-workflow, tasks

Scenario:

Have a SPD2007 approval workflow designed. A task is assigned to user1 and custom emails are sent. I'm not using the ootb email notification. Once the task is completed the workflow assigns a new task to user2 (the next reviewer). It's all sequential.

Issue:

I need to somehow store the taskID from the user1 task, then dump that into the custom email that is sent to user2. It is basically a "go see what user1 said [URL/dispform.aspx?ID=[TaskID], then complete your task."

Problem is I don't know how to get this value.

The emails are generated from a workflow attached to the tasks list. My conditions check the content type (collect data from...) to determine who has been assigned the task, then generate and send email. I've tried to store the taskid of user1 in a variable, but next time through the workflow the variable is empty.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Found a solution.

Stored the user1 taskID in a metadata field. Did a look-up to the field when sending the email to user2. Added it to the url string. Bingo.